# Set ostringstream to append automatically

Tags: c++, ostream

How do I append data for ostringstream objects? Assumingly:

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << '0x11';
```

How do I set it to perform `oss << 0x22` from the last known element automatically? I read through that I need to set some flag but how do I do it?

**edit**: Sorry for being very very vague about the question. Prolly the coffee is wearing off. Extending from my question above:

Does `ostringstream oss(osstringstream::app)` sets it to append everytime? My goal is to creating a string.

Comment: I don't understand. Streams always append. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What does it have to do with C-tag?

Comment: Changed the tags as `ostringstream` has nothing to do with c

Comment: Could you provide another example of what you'd like to do?

Comment: Thanks for down voting me, after all I find it quite dumb to ask this question but its not dumb to answer anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unspecified what the `app` flag does when passed to an
`ostringstream` constructor. This flag is only relevant to
`ofstream`.  On the other hand, `ostringstream` **is** a stream,
and as such, data are always inserted after the previously
inserted data, provided no seek has occured in the meantime.  This is, after all, the definition of an output stream.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `stringstream` like in your first example, it will append by default.

Answer (score -1):

That's the difference between `ate` and `app` as open mode.  `ate` position at the end after opening and then leave the write position alone (so if you want it, you can write anywhere), `app` ensure that all write is done at end of the stream.

Edit: in practice behaves differently for stringstream, so don't rely on it.

Comment: Except that `ate` and `ape` are only relevant to `filebuf` and `[oi]fstream`.  They're parameters to `open`, and have no defined meaning for `stringbuf`.  (Formally, I think passing them would be undefined behavior, since the standard doesn't specify a semantic for them.)

Comment: @James, Do you have a reference?  It was what I though but found nothing stating that ate and ape are relevant only for filebuf.  They are used in the description of open() to give the equivalent argument to fopen, but their description in ios_base doesn't need to be expanded for stringstream any more than the description of the seekdir or iostate.

Comment: Their complete semantics are described in `filebuf`; `stringbuf` only describes the effects of `in` and `out`.  But you may have a point: the table in the description of the `openmode` does summarize a semantics.  If this is applicable, though, what does `trunc` mean for a `streambuf`?  Or `binary`?  I think the question is open enough for me to submit a DR.

Comment: @James, I tried on three compilers, got three different results.  Undefined seems a good description of the current state.

Comment: Or unspecified.  Or implementation-defined.  I think some additional text in the standard would be appropriate.